# Nested transitions / animations in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, swiftui, transition

The goal is to create a view on top on another view, that has elements and changes color while moving away to the top of the screen. So we have one variable / state that triggers an animation where both views have sub transitions / animations.
Problem is: there is either no movement or no colortransition at some point in the animation / transition because adding a transition somehow overwrites all the individual transitions of the elements in the stack.

**EDIT:** Due to simplicity I rearranged my code avoiding the described behaviour. But it seems like a really bad solution (repeating lots of code, if's ...) Has someone an idea how to write the following working example in a more compact/advanced way?

Working, but probably unnecessary complicated:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var signUpLoginView_active: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.orange
            if signUpLoginView_active {
                ZStack {
                    Color.white
                }
                .transition(.move(edge: .top))
                .zIndex(1)
            }
            if signUpLoginView_active {
                ZStack {
                    Color.red
                }
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top).combined(with: AnyTransition.opacity))
                .zIndex(2)
            }
            Button("test"){
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)){
                    signUpLoginView_active.toggle()
                }
            }.zIndex(3)
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

My Approach to simplify (not working correctly):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var signUpLoginView_active: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.orange
            if signUpLoginView_active {
                ZStack {
                    Color.white
                    Color.red.opacity(signUpLoginView_active ? 1 : 0)
                }
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top))
            }
            Button("test"){
                withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                    signUpLoginView_active.toggle()
                }
            }
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it might get more tricky than this simple answer, you can `combine` transitions together so they take effect seamlessly:

```swift
.transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top)
            .combined(with: AnyTransition.scale))
```

In an optimal case, you should not need those `AnyTransition`s:

```swift
.transition(.move(edge: .top)
            .combined(with: .scale))
```

but it sometimes results in an Xcode error, which might or might not give any clue of the real problem that Xcode has with your code.

Optionally you might need to define whether your transitions should take effect only on `removal` or `insertion`, or ask for different Transitions on each of `removal` or `insertion`:

```swift
.transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: AnyTransition.move(edge: .top),
                                 removal: AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
            .combined(with: AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .scale,
                                                     removal: .identity)))
                                        // `.identity` means no transition
```

Comment: That's a good idea, sadly it does not fix. it. Your suggestion with a combination applies the combination of animations to all the elements in the stack. The actual goal is to .move the entire stack, but only change opacity for one element in Stack.

Comment: I found one way now with your suggestions, but I doubt that its a good way to implement the idea...any thoughts? I wonder if I'm actually the only person trying to archive such an animation, hm. Couldn't find any more documentation on that.

Comment: I find transitions a little bit tricky, so i can't say more things since i'm not sure before i try them. I'm not sure what have you tried, but my best guess is that you should try to calculate the distance that your cell should travel, to get to the top of the screen, and use AnyTransition.offset() + that calculated value. Otherwise, you might need to make a custom transition...

Comment: @lennardkorte I am trying to do this! Did you find a solution?